# How to configure docker and postgres to use pact broker

Tags: postgresql, docker

[localhost to view pacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1f4h.png)

I have installed brew version of postgres and docker.
Followed the steps in the link https://github.com/DiUS/pact_broker-docker/blob/master/POSTGRESQL.md to create a dockerised pact broker and postgres.

When I run the first command, container got created with error:

```
docker run --name pactbroker-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ThePostgresPassword -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -v /var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

Response:

```
 b8a2007e5dac9554e0ac615147d74467ceb6043dba027a4a21388721cee8f34c
    docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: 
    The path /var/lib/postgresql/data
    is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
    You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing...
```

Somehow managed to bypass the first step by removing the bind volume option:

```
docker run --name pactbroker-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ThePostgresPassword -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -d postgres
```

Succeeded 2 and 3 steps in the link specified:
(2)Connect to the container and execute psql via:
(3)Start the PactBroker container via:

After this, tried to curl json using the below command:

```
 curl -v -XPUT -H “Content-Type: application/json” -d @/HelloWorldConsumer-HelloWorldProvider.json http://localhost/pacts/provider/HelloWorldProvider/consumer/HelloWorldConsumer/version/1.0
```

Getting the below response...

```
Could not resolve host: application
* Closing connection 0
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
    *   Trying ::1...
    * connect to ::1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
    *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
    * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#1)
    > PUT /pacts/provider/HelloWorldProvider/consumer/HelloWorldConsumer/version/1.0 HTTP/1.1
    > Host: localhost
    > User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
    > Accept: */*
    > Content-Length: 756
    > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    > 
    * upload completely sent off: 756 out of 756 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
    < Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
    < Content-Length: 0
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Status: 415 Unsupported Media Type
    < Date: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 17:08:40 GMT
    < Server: Webmachine-Ruby/1.4.0 Rack/1.2
    < X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.0.15
    < 
    * Connection #1 to host localhost left intact
```

Not sure whether its success or failure as the first line saying... 'Couldn't resolve host:application' and 'Closing connection'

And when I tried to view the localhost, it appears blank.
Screenshot attached.
Looking out for help as early as possible !! Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is clearly not a pact question, but a docker question, specifically around Postgres SQL server.  I'm going to report this question as not relevant unless you want to change the question to something Pact specific.

Comment: Thanks ! Edited and added tag to docker/Postgres

Comment: Thanks.  I would probably re-word the question a bit though if you're asking a different audience so they don't get confused with pact.

Comment: Ok, Have no issues !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are attempting to mount a volume on your host machine (`/var/lib/postgresql/data`) that does not exist.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: 
The path /var/lib/postgresql/data
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
```

The message clearly states this. You should [read more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) about docker volumes, but I'd suggest you mount another directory if this is for development on your Mac.

Secondly, you can see that you're getting an "Unsupported media type" on the upload so it has definitely failed:

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

It appears as though the Content-Type is not being correctly set, you can see this in the output:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Please check that the file actually exists at path `/HelloWorldConsumer-HelloWorldProvider.json`, that it is a valid JSON file, and that your content type header is formatted correctly (it appears to be).

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your reply ! Will read about docker volume, correct it and also verify the content-type. Will get back if I din't get through with a proper question.

Comment: Thanks Mathew ! It worked... Created data cluster postgresql using initdb command. mkdir ~/.postgres and initdb ~/.postgres So my command will look like... docker run --name pactbroker-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ThePostgresPassword -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -v ~/.postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres. Also for the second issue - unsupported data type.. it's just double quotes formatted incorrectly - changed this “Content-Type: text/html” to "Content-Type: text/html". And it worked like a charm.

Comment: Great to hear @JananiSampathKumar! Can you please mark my answer as correct?